# Session is not working if php.ini file is present other than root

Tags: session

I am implementing the video uploading in my project.if i include php.ini in any folder other than root, session is not working. php.ini file is

```
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 64M;
max_execution_time = 30;
upload_max_filesize = 512M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.use_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 12000000;
```

This file is in users folder where a user can log in to upload a video.If i  remove this file,session working properly but video uploading failed.so what is my mistake, please guide me.I have tried for many solution regarding the sessions suggested in stackoverflow,but failed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

php.ini file should be renamed as **.user.ini**,then it will work.This file should be placed in folder where uploading code is written.Session is also working now.